# How to add PHP echo string from database in existing CSS layout

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm new to PHP and MySQL databases and I have successfully created a little search engine for my personal site.

But I have encountered a problem that I can't solve on my own:

**How can I display the PHP echo string (search results) within the framework of my existing site layout?**

When I try to place the PHP code where I want it to be displayed, it seems to override any CSS styling rendering only an unstyled page.

And a last question:

**How can I get the echo result styled according to my CSS file?**

Comment: You should add details and sample code

Comment: I can't post my entire code since it has too many characters, but the echo string is as follows:  <br>

echo "<div class='search_result'>
  <h2>$site_title</h2>
  <a href='$site_link'target='_blank'>Lær mer om $site_sp ved å klikke her</a>
  <p align='justify'>$site_desc</p> 
  <img src='/search-engine/images/$site_image' width='134' height='106' />  <br>
  <br>
  <hr>
  </div>";

Answer (score 0):

just an example:

```
<style>
...
.search_result{
...
}
</style>

<div class="search_result">
<?php
   echo $your_search_result;
?>
</div>
```

hope you understand.